# transaction fees included in blocks mined on the ropsten testnet

Tags: gas, block-reward

[image]

As you can see here ^, the first two times I mined a block on the Ropsten testnet I just got the block reward of `5` ethers, I guess this is because there were no gas fees/transaction fees included in those blocks, but in the latest block I mined, it worked out to `5.116374`, this is because that block contained actual transactions for me to process, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the third block you mined had 1 transaction and you received the fee from it.  You can click on the block (1375519), and then click on the transactions to see further details:

```
Gas Used By Txn: 290935
Gas Price: 0.0000004 Ether (400 Gwei)
Actual Tx Cost/Fee: 0.116374 Ether ($0.000000)
```